# Get an attribute of the last record in a django model filtering by user id

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the attribute "query" of the last record in a django model called "conversation" filtering by user id.
I used this code but it didn't work :

```py
if Conversation.objects.filter(user=request.user, query='question').last:
    ...
```

and

```py
if Conversation.objects.filter(user=request.user).last.query = 'question':
    ...
```

the conversation model :

```py
class Conversation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    query = models.TextField()
    response = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.query

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
```

Please help me through that and thanks in advance

Comment: [last()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#last) is a method not a property, so you need the brackets to invoke it.

Comment: YES last()  it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```py
Conversation.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('id')[-1:].query
```

Breaking down:

1. Conversation.objects: that's all the objects
2. .filter(user=request.user): only receives queryset from a user
3. .order_by('id'): sort it by the id. If it's the wrong direction, use -id instead of id
4. [-1:] List slicing in Python
5. .query: the model attribute that you want to get

Comment: Psst...not a list comprehension but a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice).

Comment: i tried your solution bet it gets me this error : AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.

Comment: thanks all for your suggestions i just fixed like that if Conversation.objects.filter(user=request.user).last().query == 'question':